# Unable to fetch google cloud bucket image from react.js

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
    componentDidMount(){
        let default_image = localStorage.getItem("default_image");
        const url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/smart-staging-bucket/tryon/images/default/2021-03-14/face.jpg'
        const fileName = 'myFile.jpg'
        fetch(url)
        .then(async response => {
            const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
            const blob = await response.blob()
            const file = new File([blob], fileName, { contentType })
            this.setState({
            default_image: file
            })
        })
    }
```

Here i am tying to fetch image from google cloud bucket.
But, i am getting below error.Is there any way i can fix it ?

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/smart-staging-bucket/tryon/images/default/2021-03-14/face.jpg' from origin
    'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
    resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Did you check [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Same-Origin Policy is preventing `fetch` from querying the image. You need to set up Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for your Cloud Storage Bucket -- see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors).

For example,

```
echo '[{ "origin": ["https://your-site.com"], "method": ["GET"] }]' >cors.json
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket
```